# Calling a coroutine within a coroutine while there is an event loop running in the bg

Tags: python, python-asyncio, python-3.11, pyscript

I built a coro function within a pyscript tag that outputs a location of the space station using folium to the web

```
        from pyodide.http import pyfetch
        import asyncio
        import folium

        async def get_ISS_locdata():
            response = await pyfetch("http://api.open-notify.org/iss-now.json", method="GET")
            data = await response.json()
            iss_pos = data.get("iss_position")
            latitude = iss_pos["latitude"]
            longitude = iss_pos["longitude"]

            iss_coords = [float(latitude), float(longitude)]
            iss_map = folium.Map(location = iss_coords, zoom_start = 3)
            folium.Marker(iss_coords, icon=icon, popup="<h4>International Space Station</h4>").add_to(iss_map)
            iss_map

            Element("map").write(iss_map)

            output = f"ISS Current Location - Latitude: {latitude}, Longitude: {longitude}"
            Element("output").write(output)
```

since pyscript is a running event loop,
`<pyscript._event_loop.PyscriptWebLoop object at 0x10b8470>`

I call the coro like this:
`asyncio.ensure_future(get_ISS_locdata())`

It worked.

Then I tried to create a coro interval function to update latitude and longitude of the space station:

```
async def interval(seconds, func):
            while True:
                await func()
                await asyncio.sleep(seconds)
        
       
asyncio.ensure_future(interval(3, get_ISS_locdata()))
```

and gave me an error:

```
Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-17' coro=<interval() done, defined at <exec>:28> exception=TypeError("'coroutine' object is not callable")>
sys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'get_ISS_locdata' was never awaited
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
```

I also did to ensure future and create task but same error occured.

Is there other way to call the get_ISS_locdata coro?

Comment: The `()` after `get_ISS_locdata` created and returned already a coroutine. You then tried to call it again with `func()`. Instead await `func` only.